# How do i use pyclustering to implement kmedoids?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

I am not sure how I used kmedoids in python. I have installed the pyclustering module from https://pypi.org/project/pyclustering/ yet I'm not sure how i call kmedoids? I am trying to implement PAM on my gower distance matrix.

I'm trying to cluster features from an trade dataset. I used this https://sourceforge.net/projects/gower-distance-4python/files/ to calculate gower distance on my matrix. Then i use this matrix which i've called D to pass through PAM/kmedoids

```
import pyclustering
import pyclustering.cluster.kmedoids
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import pairwise_distances
import numpy as np    

D = gower_distances(trade_data)
pam=pyclustering.kmedoids(D)

AttributeError: module 'pyclustering' has no attribute 'kmedoids'
```

I get the above error how do I call kmedoids/ use PAM?

Comment: Note that pyclustering currently does *not* implement the PAM algorithm, but a worse variant of kmedoids. See https://github.com/annoviko/pyclustering/pull/500 for the bug report.

Comment: A very small code example on an already available distance matrix is at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94172/how-to-perform-k-medoids-when-having-the-distance-matrix/470141#470141

Answer (score 4):

You need to correct import and K-Medoids initialization:

```
from pyclustering.cluster.kmedoids import kmedoids
... ...
pam=kmedoids(D, initial_medoids)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to import kmedoids as

```
from pyclustering.cluster.kmedoids import kmedoids
```

You can read more about it in pyclustering's documentation here https://codedocs.xyz/annoviko/pyclustering/classpyclustering_1_1cluster_1_1kmedoids_1_1kmedoids.html

Answer (score 1):

This is a very small code example from https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94172/how-to-perform-k-medoids-when-having-the-distance-matrix/470141#470141. It starts with an already given distance matrix, you use the gower_distances() then.

```
from pyclustering.cluster.kmedoids import kmedoids
import numpy as np

dm = np.array(
    [[0.,1.91,2.23,3.14,4.25,3.37],
    [0.,0.,2.15,1.82,2.41,2.58],
    [0.,0.,0.,3.12,3.83,4.64],
    [0.,0.,0.,0.,1.9,2.66],
    [0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,3.12],
    [0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.]])
dm = dm + np.transpose(dm)
k = 2
# choose medoid 2 and 4 in your C1 and C2 because min(D) in their cluster
initial_medoids = [1,3]
kmedoids_instance = kmedoids(dm, initial_medoids, data_type = 'distance_matrix')
# Run cluster analysis and obtain results.
kmedoids_instance.process()
clusters = kmedoids_instance.get_clusters()
centers = kmedoids_instance.get_medoids()
print(clusters)
# [[1, 0, 2, 5], [3, 4]]
print(centers)
# [1, 3]
```